# Cannot invoke method multiply() on null object groovy

Tags: gradle, groovy, build, build.gradle

Consider below code

```
task circle {
doLast {
    float r = Float.parseFloat(project.properties["radius"])
    println (22/7)*(r ** 2)
}
}
task square {
     doLast {
       float s = Float.parseFloat(project.properties["side"])
       println s*s
     }
}
```

This give error as `Cannot invoke method multiply() on null object`

If I change the above code as below then it goes fine

```
task circle {
doLast {
    float r = Float.parseFloat(project.properties["radius"])
    println 22/7*(r ** 2)
}
}
task square {
     doLast {
       float s = Float.parseFloat(project.properties["side"])
       println s*s
     }
}
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: `(println(22/7))*(r ** 2)` is what groovy sees. the result of println is null.

Comment: @cfrick is right. In the expression `println(x)*y` first `println(x)` is evaluated which returns null. Then `null * y` gives that error. you must write your expression like this: `println (x*y)`. Nice question, though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is the missing parens for the actual `println`, that
will lead to the following code being executed `(println(22/7))*(r ** 2)`.  The `println` is done first and its result (`void`) becomes
`null`. And then it throws the error you are seeing. Your "not-throwing"
example nudges the parser in the right direction.

Parens in groovy are "optional if unambiguous", which is quite a broad
term.  Granted, that this got better with the new parrot-parser, you
will often see things like this blow up.  Simple rule of thumb: just
don't leave out the parens for calling functions unless you are dealing
with a trivial term.

Comment: Optional parenthesis are quite confusing in groovy, especially for beginners. So if you see `a b` this means actually `a(b)`. What about this one: `a (b) c`? Well this this is similar with our case and means `(a(b))(c)` where `a(b)` was evaluated with null, like already mentioned.